# nltest dclist does not show same result

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory, windows-authentication

We have two Windows 2012 servers reside on the same subnet on domain "FACTORY".
And we have intermittent authentication issue(3rd party app) with users from domain "OFFICE".
During troubleshooting using **nltest** command, something which I don't understand.

Here is the output from **the first Windows 2021 server**:

```
nltest /dclist:OFFICE
Get list of DCs in domain 'OFFICE' from '\\DC01'.
You don't have access to DsBind to OFFICE (\\DC01) (Trying NetServerEnum).
I_NetGetDCList failed: Status = 6118 0x17e6 ERROR_NO_BROWSER_SERVERS_FOUND
```

Here is the output from **the second Windows 2012 server**:

```
nltest /dclist:OFFICE
Get list of DCs in domain 'OFFICE' from '\\DC02'.
You don't have access to DsBind to OFFICE (\\DC02) (Trying NetServerEnum).
List of DCs in Domain OFFICE
    \\DC03 (PDC)
The command completed successfully
```

**Why the 2nd Windows 2012 could get list of DCs in Domain OFFICE?** Both servers are located on the same network subnet, both have the same network settings, no WINS. I can see that the nltest was using different DC (DC01 vs DC02) to get the result, which I also don't understand.

I was reading a lot of articles about the error ERROR_NO_BROWSER_SERVERS_FOUND, which pointed to "Computer Browser Service". However, this service is disabled on both servers.

The intermittent authentication issue has never been reported from the 2nd Windows 2012, so I would suspect this nltest result might contribute to that.

Answer (score 0):

- What's the domain topology?
- What kind of trust is it?
- Are there any error events from NETLOGON in the DC event logs on either side?
- Does `nltest /trusted_domains` show the correct info on the FACTORY DCs
- Does `nltest /sc_query:OtherDomain` show any errors on the Trusting side?
- Same with `netdom trust TrustingDomainName /domain:TrustedDomainName /verify` on each of the DCs on each side of the trust? (Or you can check it in AD Domains and Trusts). Unlike `nltest`, this requires credentials.
- Are [all the required ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/config-firewall-for-ad-domains-and-trusts), including all the required RPC ports, open between all the DCs in each domain? And in Windows Firewall? The most important aspect is that the Trusting domain DCs must be able to get to the PDCE in the Trusted domain. At the very least, you need these ports: LDAP (389 UDP and TCP), SMB (445 TCP), Kerberos (88 UDP), RPC portmapper (135 TCP), DNS (53 UDP and TCP)
- Have you tried DNS queries from all the DCs to see if you can resolve the SRVs on each side? e.g. `nslookup -q=SRV _ldap._tcp.mydomain.com` (and the same for `_kerberos.tcp` and `_kerberos.udp`)
- Do any of the DCs in either domain have the same hostname? Or duplicate SIDs? If the DCs were built from a custom image, were they Sysprepped?
- Is the time in sync on all DCs on both sides of the trust? (Within 5 minutes, maximum)
- Any errors in NETLOGON.LOG? You can enable NETLOGON debug logging for richer information, but only leave it on for a short time.